# ClickOnce: Update Custom Folder

Tags: .net, deployment, clickonce, directory

I am making an ClickOnce Installation setup. I have to keep a custom folder in system folder, that has certain DLLs that are used by application at run time. So, I made a separate installer for these DLLs and created a Custom Boot Strapper that I use as a pre-requisite in ClickOnce installer.

What I need is, when Application updates itself using Clickonce, it should also update that custom folder in System  folder.

Is there any way to accomplish this, i.e to tell clickonce to update that custom folder also ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. ClickOnce can't update files outside of your user profile.

You can have ClickOnce download the latest version of your system dlls, but copying them to the system directory would have to be done with your own code after your application starts, assuming the dlls aren't already in use and can't be overwritten.

Comment: yeah.I figured that out after lot of time. anyways thanks for you reply :)