# Copy folder contexts using ClickOnce Publish in VS

Tags: visual-studio, installation, clickonce, publish

I use VS 2019's publish feature to create a ClickOnce installer which sits on a server. When someone installs or updates their version of the exe, I need a folder of files to be copied to a specific folder on their local machine. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.tools.applications.deployment.iaddinpostdeploymentaction?view=vsto-2017) seems to be the closest I could find to do what I want, but it seems like its only targeted for Office add-ins. How can I do a post-deployment action or event for clickonce publishing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ClickOnce: Update Custom Folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078612/clickonce-update-custom-folder)

Comment: It is impossible to move some files from the bin folder to another location only during install or updating through clickonce.